# ways of monitoring filesystem for new files and ship them to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Thanks for reading!. I have the following problem.

I have a filesystem where new files are regularly pushed into.

/year/month/day/xxxxxxxx.csv

1. I need to monitor the filesystem for new files
2. I need to convert them to JSON
3. I need to ship them to Elasticsearch.

I am wondering what is the most reliable way of doing this.

I was looking at logstash but I am not sure how reliable is the filesystem monitoring bit. Also the file-server is actually a Windows machine.

Also I really want a fool-proof but very simple solution with not too many moving parts.

is there any simple library there that is specialized on file-system monitorig with a simple way to transform a given fileformat into JSON and bulk import it into Elasticsearch ?

Thanks for any advise or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filebeat might help. Then you send the stream to logstash and apply a CSV filter.

Fscrawler do this monitoring for sure but only for JSON files or PDF/oOo/Office and the like docs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, we created Ambar for the same purpose as you described. It can crawl folder -> extract data -> submit to ElasticSearch. Check our website for more information https://ambar.cloud

Also another great service is FsCrawler, which was mentioned by @dadoonet